# Sql server- Does renaming a table name have any bad effects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I know this is a broad question but there doesn't seem to be resources online to answer my doubt.

I noticed if I rename a table in `sql server`, it would prompt a message saying it might affect or break the roots of the tables.

What does that mean?

Does it actually break the stored procedure or script ?

Comment: If you reference something by that name, then change it, yes, it is broken. It does not rename every instance of that table name.

Comment: If you rename a column, you should consider if you have any frontend applications on that table. They will break then. Views will break too if you have specified a specific column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. It will break the routines which are referring it. You can use your management studio to find objects that are referencing it:

[image]

or the following script:

```
DECLARE @SearchWord NVARCHAR(128) = 'table'

SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%' 
UNION
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) 
FROM SYSCOMMENTS 
WHERE [text] LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%' 
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
UNION 
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%' 

RETURN

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.table', 'OBJECT')

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.table', 'OBJECT')
```

Also, it will be best if you look for your server side files (asp, .net) and check if the table is used in SSIS packages or in reporting files (.rdl).

Comment: Can creating a SYNONYM help to avoid breaking something when you rename a table?

Comment: We have done something like this in our production. `DROP TABLE` in order to apply normalization (the table was split to five separate tables) and then create a `view` with the same name as the initial table name - the view itself was select from the new tables. This was good, because we are not able to rewrite the all old code, but we want to optimize the new one.

Comment: I guess [synonyms](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Synonyms/115072/) might be even better. Just rename the table. Then use `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.OldTableName FOR dbo.NewTableName;` and all code that referred to the old table-name will still work, even the query optimizer is not affected (as opposed to views). But i've never used them myself, that's why i've asked.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the existence of the `SCHEMABINDING` option for [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) and UDFs. These allow you to ensure that the underlying tables/views upon which the View or UDF depends aren't changed (such as by being renamed).

But note that a) it's an *option* that's off by default and b) it's not available for stored procedures, which go completely in the other direction by having deferred name resolution.

So yes, Views, UDFs and Stored Procedure definitions can all be invalidated by renaming a table, and you can only protect the first two by employing `SCHEMABINDING`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an image and some code that shows for example your views will break if you dont know what effects your changed column has.

**Create view**

[image]

**Edit column name and select from view**
[image]

**Code**

```
   /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

  /*Main table*/
 SELECT TOP 1000 [Person]
     ,[Book]
 FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[Books]


 /*Create view*/
 create view dbo.booksview as

 select person,Book from dbo.Books

 /*Selcet from view*/
 Select * from dbo.booksview


 /*Change column name*/
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Books]    Script Date: 03-11-2017 09:42:52 ******/
  DROP TABLE [dbo].[Books]
 GO

 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Books]    Script Date: 03-11-2017 09:42:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books](
[PersonNEW] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Book] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/*Select from view again with Person changed to PersonNew*/
Select * from dbo.booksview
```